# Accessing an entire row of a multidimensional array in C++

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

How would one access an entire row of a multidimensional array?
For example:

```
int logic[4][9] = {
    {0,1,8,8,8,8,8,1,1},
    {1,0,1,1,8,8,8,1,1},
    {8,1,0,1,8,8,8,8,1},
    {8,1,1,0,1,1,8,8,1}
};

// I want everything in row 2. So I try...
int temp[9] = logic[2];
```

My attempt throws the error:

> array initialization needs curly braces

I know I can retrieve the row using a FOR loop, however I'm curious if there was a more obvious solution.

Comment: Possible alternative: `std::vector<int> temp(std::begin(logic[2]), std::end(logic[2]));` ?

Comment: Arrays aren't too C++. Use an `std::vector` if you can.

Comment: You could look into [`valarray`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/valarray) and [`slice`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/valarray/slice).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's not how arrays/pointers work in C++.

That array is stored somewhere in memory. In order to reference the same data, you'll want a pointer that points to the the beginning of the array:

```
int* temp = logic[2];
```

Or if you need a copy of that array, you'll have to allocate more space.

Statically:

```
int temp[9];
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    temp[i] = logic[2][i];
}
```

Dynamically:

```
// allocate
int* temp = new int(9);
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    temp[i] = logic[2][i];
}

// when you're done with it, deallocate
delete [] temp;
```

Or since you're using C++, if you want to not worry about all this memory stuff and pointers, then you should use `std::vector<int>` for dynamically sized arrays and `std::array<int>` for statically sized arrays.

```
#include <array>
using namespace std;

array<array<int, 9>, 4> logic = {
  {0,1,8,8,8,8,8,1,1},
  {1,0,1,1,8,8,8,1,1},
  {8,1,0,1,8,8,8,8,1},
  {8,1,1,0,1,1,8,8,1}
}};

array<int, 9> temp = logic[2];
```

Answer (score 5):

As well as decaying the array to a pointer, you can also bind it to a reference:

```
int (&temp)[9] = logic[2];
```

One advantage of this is it will allow you to use it C++11 range-based for loops:

```
for (auto t : temp) {
  // stuff
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A direct assignment won't work. C++ does not allow that. At best you'll be able to assign them to point to the same data - `int *temp = logic[2]`. You'll need a for loop or something like the below.

I believe this would work:

```
int temp[9];
memcpy(temp, logic[2], sizeof(temp));
```

But I'd generally suggest using `std::vector` or `std::array` instead.